# Backbone.Events context issue in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: backbone.js, titanium-mobile, backbone-events

I have a custom library in my Titanium Mobile (3.1.0 GA SDK) project that looks something like this:

```
// lib/MyObject.js
function MyObject
{
    var self = this;
    _.extend(self, Backbone.Events);

    this.trigger('myEvent');
}

module.exports = MyObject;
```

In another part of my application, I make the class available globally:

```
Alloy.Globals.MyObject = require('MyObject');
```

And in a controller, I instantiate it:

```
var myObj = new Alloy.Globals.MyObject();
```

That object gets passed around a bit, until finally an event listener is added:

```
// In another controller
myObj.on('myEvent', function() {
    console.log('My event happened!');
};
```

Unfortunately, log command never gets called.  If I add an event listener within the MyObject function, it works fine.  But it won't work when called from outside the object.

I would just assume that there's a bug in there, or the object is getting passed by value instead of reference, except for this.  If I change the class definition to the following:

```
// lib/MyObject.js
function MyObject
{
    var self = this;
    _.extend(self, Backbone.Events);

    var old_on = this.on;
    this.on = function(a, b, c) {
        return old_on.call(self, a, b, c);
    };

    this.trigger('myEvent');
}

module.exports = MyObject;
```

...everything works.  Somehow the `on` function is not getting the correct context, but I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Anyone have insight into what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, updating to the 3.1.1.GA SDK version fixed it.  Must've been a bug in Titanium.